# About Kali's these sons

Tags: puranas

In the 59th chapter of 3rd Canto of Brahmanda Purana, it is mentioned that four of Kali's son are popular:-

> 10. Four other sons were born to Kali. They were cannibals. They were **Nāka, and Vighna who were very famous, as well as Bhadrama and Vidhama**.

AFAIK, all of 18 Maha Puranas (expect Brahmanda Purana) never mentioned them. However, any Upa Puranas and other scripture mention any details about them (other than their birth and family)?